# Regarding [Exodus 4:22] , [Deuteronomy 14:1], [Hosea 11:1], does Salvation refer to "Yisrael" in [John 3:18]?

Tags: israel

Regarding [Exodus 4:22] , [Deuteronomy 14:1], [Hosea 11:1], does the anointed Salvation (ישׁוּעָ) refer to "Yisrael" (יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל) in [John 3:18]?

Comment: I am really struggling to understand what you are asking here.  None of these texts even mentions salvation.  Only two mention Israel.

Comment: @NigelJ - Jesus Christ is the mistransliterated title Yeshua Meshiach which literally means ‘anointed salvation’. So yes - Salvation is anointed.

Comment: @ctaylorgraphics I am aware of your view on these points. And I disagree. No further comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is Jesus Christ himself, personally, who is anointed (the reason for the title 'Christ').

'Salvation' is not anointed. Salvation is a concept, not a person, and cannot be 'anointed' by the descent and infilling  of another person - the Holy Spirit.

Figuratively, objects can be 'anointed' with oil. But the reality of the figure involves two **persons.**

---

As to salvation, in Acts 4 Peter tells us that :

> (10) Be it known unto you all, and to **all the people of Israel**, that by the **name of Jesus Christ** of Nazareth, whom ye crucified, whom God raised from the dead, even by him doth this man stand here before you whole.

> (11)This is the stone which was set at nought of you builders, which is become the head of the corner.

> (12) **Neither is there salvation in any other**: for there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved.

Salvation is clearly not in the name 'Israel'.

Salvation came 'out of' Israel, meaning that Jesus Christ is come, according to the flesh 'out of' Israel. That is how he came. And,  more strictly speaking, as Paul says in Romans 11:26, 'There shall come out of **Sion** the Deliverer'.

But the name 'Israel' does not save.

Peter makes it clear that only by the name of 'Jesus Christ' is there salvation.

(And  not the name 'Joshua' I would add, for that is to confuse the Person of Jesus of Nazareth with another person who is an historic, Jewish person, whose bones still remain on this earth, whilst Jesus Christ is resurrected and ascended up on high, and is seated at the right hand of God as scripture plainly declares, Psalm 68:18, Ephesians 4:8, plus . . . [one hundred verses regarding Jesus sitting at the right hand of the Father](https://www.openbible.info/topics/jesus_sitting_at_the_right_hand_of_the_father).)